# What exactly prevents there from being a free OS like IBM's self-maintaining "z" OS?

Tags: philosophy

> IBM designed IBM i as a "turnkey" operating system, requiring little or no on-site attention from IT staff during normal operation.

This is a dream of mine. Unfortunately, it costs a million dollars per nanosecond and I have $0 budget.

The opposite of this dream is the *nightmare* of being forced to manually babysit and update/mess with "some Linux distro". While some apparently have the ability to self-update, I went insane trying to actually enable this and communicate with the community about how to interpret the manual. Eventually, I gave up on it, since it was clearly not meant to be enabled, and if the system patches in FreeBSD are anything to go by, it would quickly brick the machine since those patches kept breaking everything even when manually applying them. I spent countless nights sweating and swearing with a bricked server somewhere across the world in a data center and me only having some fragile connection (if any at all) to try to fix the issues causes by the broken patches with zero support or even useful documentation.

What exactly is it that makes this IBM OS able to maintain itself? Again, I have $0 to spend, so even having two servers where I can apply updates on one while the other is actively serving, and then "switch over" only when the other is done, is entirely unrealistic to me. But even that would be a nightmare to me, something which I have zero interest in ever subjecting myself to. I don't exaggerate when I say that maintaining even a single server caused me to lose my mental health, for real, with all the constant stress and worry this caused.

A "managed" server is even more expensive, and that requires trusting "unknown bunglers" as well, which I don't. I barely trust myself.

What stops a free-of-charge OS, maybe called something like "Turnkey Linux", from maintaining itself by default and without bricking itself or any software installed? The supported software can be very limited, as long as it includes PHP and PostgreSQL.

Why is this not a thing? There must be a good reason.

Comment: (Decades of experience. Not just with machines and operating them, software systems to that end and customers for all that, but also with the market.)

Answer (score 1):

> What exactly is it that makes this IBM OS able to maintain itself?

It's not clear what you mean by that. IBM i certainly does not maintain itself. In the companies I know that use IBM i, an OS update is a big f…ing deal that involves shutting down most operations in the entire company and the entire IT department pulling an all-weekender.

In the company I know best, they had a large machine for production, and two older, smaller machines for development and testing. Usually, one of the development and testing machines would run the same versions as the production machine, and the other one would run the next OS release. When it came time to update the production machine, they would first update one of the development machines to the exact versions that the production machine was currently running and the other one to the exact versions that they wanted to update to.

Then, they would start migrating their applications to the new OS release, which took anywhere from a couple of weeks to a couple of months. Once they had migrated and tested all applications to the new OS release, they set a date for doing the migration, which was always on a weekend, preferably a long weekend with a bank holiday on Friday or Monday.

On Friday afternoon, they would stop all business processes as far as possible (which in itself required weeks of planning and prior warning) and move the processes that couldn't be stopped to the development machine. (Note that the development machine was much smaller and much older, so it could only take the load of the few most essential services.)

Then, they updated the production machine, which typically takes an entire day, installed the updated versions of the applications, and after thorough testing, moved the processes back to the now updated production machine.

In later years, the company had grown so much that it was not possible to do this process anymore within the timeframe of one weekend, so instead they rented an identical clone of their production machine from IBM for a couple of weeks, so they could run the old and new OS in parallel and migrate the applications one-by-one.

> What stops a free-of-charge OS, maybe called something like "Turnkey Linux", from maintaining itself by default and without bricking itself or any software installed?

Nothing stops it from doing so.

Or, to be more precise: the Free Software / Open Source *community* is a *community*. In a community, people pitch in with their help. So, for *every* question of the form "why doesn't the community do X", the answer is *always* "because there are only people asking why the community is not doing X and no people doing X".

Free Software / Open Source projects have the *unique* feature that if there is something you don't like about them, *you have the power to change it*. However, the change will only come about *if* you **do** something about it. Complaining is not doing.

And, by the way, my WiFi router *is* a Linux computer that completely maintains and updates itself, so the thing that you are asking why it doesn't exist, actually *does* exist.